# Codeigniter: IF(condition){ insert table1 } ELSE { insert into another table}

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

Is it possible??

```
if(selectboxValue == Trending_blog)
{
    insert into trendingTable;
} else {
    insert into anotherTable;
}
```

I want to do it in codeigniter. If the selct box selected value is trending, then i want to insert that blog in trendingTable, else if the value is something else then i want to insert it in anotherTable.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What is the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in codeigniter using controller and model

Comment: yes, if you had written code rather than asking here, you would got your answer by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($this->input->post('selectname') == 'Trending_blog'){
$this->db->insert('tbl1',$data);
}
else{
$this->db->insert('tbl2',$data);
}

//You can try this code
```